# Creating Canvas Elements from Image Elements Dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, html5-canvas

I'm trying to loop through all the img tags on my page and dynamically create a canvas element for each img (so I can modify pixel values with JavaScript). However, although my code currently is adding my canvases to the page, they remain blank. I don't know if it's the way I am using the drawImage() function, some greater problem with the structure of the code or something else entirely?

```
var images = [], canvas = [], context = [];

function init() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  // Create a canvas for each image...
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    canvas[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
    context[i] = canvas[i].getContext('2d');
    context[i].drawImage(images[i], 0, 0);
    document.body.appendChild(canvas[i]);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, **without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.**

You are painting unloaded images. You should either wait for the entire page to load, or add an event listener to each image that will draw its canvas when the image is loaded. I'll go for the second, so the images are created instantly, instead after all stylesheets and everything is loaded.

```
var images = [], canvas = [], context = [];

function init() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  // Create a canvas for each image...
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("load", (function(i) {
      canvas[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
      context[i] = canvas[i].getContext('2d');
      context[i].drawImage(images[i], 0, 0);
      document.body.appendChild(canvas[i]);
    }).bind(null, i)); // Bind to contextualize the variable so don't changes before the event is called because of the loop. As others may think, `i` is not overwritten by the event parameter, so this bind is safe.
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.bind(null, i)`, since the first argument of `bind` is the `this` context to run the function in?